# Update query with multiple subqueries

Tags: mysql

Here is the update I'm trying to run:

```
UPDATE  oc_product_gpf SET
brand =  '(select name from oc_manufacturer where manufacturer_id=
(select manufacturer_id from oc_product where product_id = oc_product_gpf.product_id) )'
WHERE  oc_product_gpf.gpf_id =2454;
```

The error I'm receiving is  '#1406 - Data too long for column 'brand' at row 1'

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: that's not a subquery. it's a STRING containing some text that LOOKS like a query. but since it's a string, that "kinda looks like sql" is NOT executed. Remove the `'`.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query
and try to explain what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your subquery not acting as a subquery here. it simply act as a string and trying to assign to "brand" column. Please remove the '' or convert that in to a join